# Core Data crash when not connect to Xcode both device and simulator

Tags: core-data, ios-simulator, exc-bad-access

My app runs on both the device and in simulator when connected to Xcode. Other wise it crashes at this point (On both device / simulator when run without Xcode). Must be the debugger keeping it alive or something. I think the crash is coming from:

```
CDObject * cdObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CDObject" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];
```

I use Core Data else where in the program and it is working fine.
I've verified that the self.moc is not nil through NSLog statements. Here is part of the crash report..

```
    Date/Time:       2011-12-06 10:19:39.146 -0500
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0 (9A334)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x3d6936a8
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x362b6fca objc_msgSend + 30
1   CoreFoundation                  0x374276ea CFDictionarySetValue + 102
2   CoreData                        0x317082ec _PFCMT_SetValue + 852
3   CoreData                        0x31769b90 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _insertObjectWithGlobalID:globalID:] + 60
4   CoreData                        0x31760aba -[NSManagedObjectContext insertObject:] + 134
5   CoreData                        0x31707d56 -[NSManagedObject initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:] + 538
6   CoreData                        0x3173f5ce +[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 174
```